# In Pathfinder Society, can Deep Pockets be used to retrieve broken weapons or armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class, pathfinder-society

The Prestige Class [Pathfinder Chronicler](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/prestigeClasses/pathfinderChronicler.html#pathfinder-chronicler) gets the following ability at level 1:

> **Deep Pockets (Ex):** A Pathfinder chronicler collects items as well as lore, picking up small amounts of this or that throughout her travels. As a result, she may carry unspecified equipment worth up to 100 gp per class level. This can be any kind of gear that can reasonably fit into a backpack, including potions and scrolls (but not any other sort of magic item). As a full-round action, the chronicler may dig through her pockets to retrieve an item she specifies at that time, deducting its value from the allocated amount of cost. This item cannot weigh more than 10 pounds. When the total remaining cost reaches 0, the chronicler can retrieve no more items until she refills her deep pockets by spending a few hours and an amount of gold to bring her total up to 100 gp per class level....

Within the Pathfinder Society Roleplaying Guild Guide (page 20 for Season 8), there is a section specifying what items can be bought that includes this:

> Items must be purchased at full value. You can’t buy broken weapons or armor....

With Deep Pockets, items are being "retrieved" instead of "purchased." Can a Pathfinder Chronicler retrieve broken weapons or armor using Deep Pockets when playing PFS? In some cases, I've had to gift weapons or armor to less-than intelligent creatures in order to gain favor, and supplying them with a weapon or some armor that meets prerequisites but has less value due to the broken condition could lessen the amount of gold spent out of Deep Pockets.

Comment: To be super-clear, are you are asking about *non-weapon, non-armour* broken items, or all items, including weapons and armour?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie All items, including weapons and armor.

Comment: Since there's no conflict between the ability and PFS rules regarding non-weapon, non-armor items (the PFS rule only prohibits broken weapons or armor), I've made the question specifically about that point. Does that look good?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes. I wasn't making the distinction, but I see why it's necessary.

Comment: "I just so happened to have packed five suits of leather armour, all of them shredded to the point of uselessness. I'm still not sure why, though."

Answer (score 2):

From the text of Deep Pockets, although the items are being mechanically 'retrieved' by the ability, it seems to imply that, in-universe, the character did purchase or otherwise acquire these items previously. Even though this prior acquisition is handled abstractly, I would say that it still needs to fulfill the normal campaign-level PFS purchasing restrictions.

As a sidenote, I also don't believe you could use this ability to retrieve items that, for instance, you did not have the Fame to purchase, or were in a source you did not have access to, or were not on the Additional Resources list.

Comment: I agree with your side note, although realistically it would be hard to purchase things outside your Fame restrictions since you can't even start PfC until level 6.